# Cloudera quickstart vm docker, how can I have hdfs data stored on a mount point?

Tags: hadoop, docker, mount-point, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Using Cloudera quickstart vm I would like to process more than a few gigs of data. However I need to take the Docker container down from time to time and change it (I'm playing with the configuration). I would like this 'large' amount of data to be kept on the host and mounted when I bring the container up again.

I thought that mounting a host path to /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs will do the trick but it seems that there's some initial file system structure already in place.

Is there another deeper path that I can use for the mount point?
Any other ideas how to do this?